# Cannot load xdebug error

Tags: php, apache

Cannot load Xdebug - it was built with configuration API220090626,TS,VC9, whereas running engine is API220090626,NTS,VC9 and i seem to have had this problem without quite noticing until it comes to debugging php scripts and please can someone help me as i havent really tried to manage debug a php script scuessfully?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant xdebug bits of your php.ini

Comment: xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.max_nesting_level=250
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
zend_extension_ts=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll

Answer (score 2):

If you can load page with phpinfo() on it, look at the Architecture row. If its value is x86 you need the 32 bit version: PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (32 bit). If Architecture is x64, you need the 64 bit version: PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using PHP for Windows. There's two DLLs for xdebug since PHP comes in two flavors for Windows: Thread Safe(TS) and Non-Thread Safe(NTS). You also have to marry builds up (5.4 vs 5.5, 32 bit vs 64 bit)

Head over to the [Xdebug download page](http://xdebug.org/download.php) and get the proper DLL.

Comment: that would make sense which means i need to download a dll which is compatibale with php 5.4.18 right

Comment: IM guessing its as simple as just replacing the dll in the php folder with the thread safe from xdebug?

Comment: Correct. Determine which version of PHP you're using. So you'll need the 5.4 version that is TS/NTS and 32/64 bit. Then replace the DLL

Comment: Im getting a different message this time telling me "failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll" any ideas?

Comment: Did you rename the file after putting it in that directory?